# Como obtener contactos del dispositivo separando numeros telefonicos y numeros celulares

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion que lee los contactos del dispositivo, todo va bien pero tengo un problema, existe alguna manera de identificar los numeros celulares con los numeros telefonicos?? En mi caso un contacto puede tener 2 numeros uno de su celular y otro de su casa. Necesito identificar cual es cual...
El codigo que utilizo es:

```
        final String[] projeccion = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER};


    String selectionClause = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND "
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " IS NOT NULL";
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

    final Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            projeccion,
            selectionClause,
            null,
            sortOrder);

    HashSet<String> normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound = new HashSet<>();
    int indexOfNormalizedNumber = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER);

    while(c.moveToNext()){
        String email=c.getString(1).replace(" ","_");
        String normalizedNumber = c.getString(indexOfNormalizedNumber);
        if(normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound.add(normalizedNumber)){
         contactosAtributos=.......

            listaC.add(contactosAtributos);
        }
    }
    c.close();
```

Este codigo no me ayuda con lo que estoy requiriendo...

Comment: Eso dependería del país en el que te encuentres pues no hay forma de saber cuando un teléfono es móvil o fijo si no es por el formato que cada país le da.

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE devolverá como respuesta "The type of data, for example Home or Work."(El tipo de dato, por ejemplo Casa o Trabajo). En la clase ContactsContract puedes ver que tiene las siguientes opciones:

TYPE_HOME
TYPE_WORK
TYPE_OTHER
TYPE_MOBILE